# Powerpoint Addin for Detecting if Presentation Uses a Given Template

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create an addin (using PPT VBA) that would be able to detect whether the opened file is using a certain template or not. If it does then it should call a public sub programmed in this template.

The scenario is the following: I created my own macro-enabled PPT template and I want the users of this template to have an addin installed that would detect when they are opening that template or a PPT file using this template. I tried to add a hidden shape with a given name to the first slide of the template that the addin could check for existence in its auto_open sub. The problem is that the auto_open sub executes when Powerpoint opens, before loading the file slides! I don't think there is an auto event that fires after the slides load.

Powerpoint version is 2007 and above, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, a macro-enabled template may not be the right way to go about it.  If a user bases a new presentation on a template, the new presentation inherits the template's contents (slides, vba project, etc).  If they APPLY the template, they only get the formatting, not the content.

That may or may not be an issue for you.

Since you're providing an add-in as well, I'd be inclined to put all of the code in the add-in and stick with a plain POTX (not macro-enabled) template.

In the add-in you can trap events, specifically the PresentationOpen event, which fires when the user opens a presentation.

There's more about that here on my PPT FAQ site:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

You'll want to put any "magic" shapes on the Slide Master or one of the Layouts in the template (ie the shapes you test for to make sure it's your template and not some other one).

Comment: Thank you @steve for the reply. I actually ended up by dropping the idea of the addin for the moment as I really want to minimize the end users' intervention and avoiding them to install the addin is a plus for me now. Given this, I opted for a `<customUI>` solution. I was inspired by the article in [Here](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/PowerPoint_Auto_Open_Code.html)